# Streaming theora

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am streaming video  captured by web cam. I use the usb_cam node to capture and compress video using theora codec and the image_view node to play the stream. In order to transport data from  a computer to another remote one via wireless, I use the   ros_rt_wmp node (our node that implements a multihop protocol).

It works, but with some "strange aspects".  Video data reaches the remote node, and with remap to the  image_view node , but I am able to see the video ONLY if this  image_view node is already opened in the receiver computer and on the SENDER computer. If not, data reaches destination computer  but aren't played by the image_view.

Any idea about that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35019/streaming-theora/) by [doxsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2422/doxsi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Image transport uses a different topic for each image compression; are you sure you're forwarding the correct topics? You may also want to forward the camera_info topic.

Take a look at http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport for more information.

**EDIT 1:**

Does the remote(forwarded) image_view continue to work after you close the local image_view? If so, then the local image_view is doing some sort of setup that the remote image_view isn't able to do, probably because something isn't forwarded properly.

You may want to look at which services your camera node advertises, and try forwarding those.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1